# How to append a div to another two div with the same ID using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a tic tac toe that every cell is another tic tac toe in html/js but I want to make the structure with js. But I can't apply the function to create div in more than 1 div.

```
<script>
    function create_elements_from_html(n, html){
        const template = document.createElement("template")
        let htmlaux = ``
        for (a = 0; a < n; a += 1){
            htmlaux += html
        }

        template.innerHTML = htmlaux
        return template.content;
    }
    let big_board = create_elements_from_html(1, `<div id="big_board">big</div>`)
    document.body.appendChild(big_board)
    let small_board = create_elements_from_html(9, `<div id="small_board">small</div>`)
    document.getElementById("big_board").appendChild(small_board)
    let cell = create_elements_from_html(9, `<div id="cell">cell</div>`)
    document.getElementById("small_board").appendChild(cell)
</script>
```

I expected that this code return this but 9 times the small_board:

```
<div id="big_board"> big
    <div id="small_board"> small
        <div id = "cell"> cell</div>
        <div id = "cell"> cell</div>
        <div id = "cell"> cell</div>
        <div id = "cell"> cell</div>
        <div id = "cell"> cell</div>
        <div id = "cell"> cell</div>
        <div id = "cell"> cell</div>
        <div id = "cell"> cell</div>
        <div id = "cell"> cell</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The "id" attribute value of each element in the document must be **unique**. You cannot re-use the same id on more than one element, in other words.

Comment: Is it possible you meant to use `class` here instead of `id`?  That would make some sense.

Comment: Are you showing what you expect or what you get? because, that is not what you get - you get one populated `small_board` and 8 empty `small_board` exactly as you have written - where you add 1 x big_board, 9 x small_board and 9 x cell for a total of 19 divs

Comment: You're passing n=9 when you create small_board. Is that really what you wanted?

Comment: `trying to make a tic tac toe that every cell is another tic tac toe` suggests each 3x3 small board would contain 3x3 cells ... like a sudoku board 9x9

Answer (score 0):

Just use class and loop for cell and small boards like this:

```
function create_elements_from_html(n, html){
    const template = document.createElement("template")
    let htmlaux = ``
    for (a = 0; a < n; a += 1){
        htmlaux += html
    }

    template.innerHTML = htmlaux
    return template.content;
}
let big_board = create_elements_from_html(1, `<div class="big_board">big</div>`)
document.body.appendChild(big_board)
let small_board = create_elements_from_html(9, `<div class="small_board">small</div>`)
document.querySelector(".big_board").appendChild(small_board)
for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    let cell = create_elements_from_html(1, `<div class="cell">cell</div>`)
     document.querySelectorAll(".small_board").forEach((board) => board.appendChild(cell.cloneNode(true)))
}
```

This appends the cells (9 cells) for each small boards (9 small board) so with a result of one big board, nine small boards inside the big board each containing nine cells. And use class instead of id.
If this is what you want!